# Ошибка must have pointer to object type, что может быть?

Tags: c++

```
class Matrix{
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    int **p = nullptr;
public:
    Matrix() = default;

    Matrix(int i) : Matrix(i, i){}

    Matrix(int i, int j) :n(i), m(j)
    {
        p = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            p[i] = new int[m];
    }

    Matrix(const Matrix &ob)
    {
        n = ob.n; m = ob.m;

        p = new int*[ob.n];
        for (int i = 0; i < ob.n; i++)
            p[i] = new int[ob.m];

        for (int i = 0; i < ob.n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ob.m; j++)
                p[i][j] = ob.p[i][j];
        }
    }

    Matrix operator+(const Matrix &ob)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                p[i][j] += ob.p[i][j];
        }

        return *this;
    }
    //Не работает
    Matrix operator*(const Matrix &ob)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < m - 1; ++k)
                    p[i][j] += p[i][k] * ob.p[k][j];
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

    int &operator[](const Matrix &index)
    { 
        return p[index.n][index.m]; 
    };

    const int &operator[](const Matrix &index) const {
        return p[index.n][index.m];
    };

    ~Matrix()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            delete[] p[i];
        delete[] p;
    }

    void fill()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                p[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    void show()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                cout << p[i][j] << ' ';
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main(){
    //srand(time(NULL));

    Matrix a(5);
    a.fill();
    a.show();

    cout << a[2][1];        

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ошибка в строке cout << a[2][1];

Comment: В своем предыдущем вопросе я просил вас объяснить, какого рода индекс вы хотите применять к вашей матрице. Ничего внятного вы обяснить не смогли и вместо этого приняли первый попавшийся ответ (который, очевидно, вы даже не поняли). В результате написали вышеприведнный код, делающий ерунду. (Матрица в качестве индекса???) Теперь вы снова приняли первый попавшийся ответ, хотя он делает совсем не то, что вы приняли в первом случае...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    int **p = nullptr;

public:
    Matrix() = default;

    Matrix(int i) : Matrix(i, i)
    {
    }

    Matrix(int i, int j) :n(i), m(j)
    {
        p = new int*[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            p[i] = new int[m];
    }   

    int* operator[](const int index)
    {
        return p[index];
    };

    ~Matrix()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            delete[] p[i];
        delete[] p;
    }

    void fill()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                p[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    void show()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
                cout << p[i][j] << ' ';
            cout << '\n';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Matrix a(5);
    a.fill();
    a.show();

    cout << a[2][1];
    a[2][1] = 99;
    a.show();

    return 0;
}
```

Пример приведён только в образовательных целях, для демонстрации того факта, что
`a[x][y]` компилятор видит как `*( *(a + x) + y)`.

Поэтому (опять же в образовательных целях) можно к одномерному массиву обращаться как к двумерному, и наоборот. Далее я бы рекомендовал бы вам не использовать такой подход, уйти от Си-массивов в сторону С++-контейнеров и не перегружать операторы таким образом: от этого падает читаемость кода.

Comment: "что a[x][y] компилятор видит как<...>" - только в случае с указателями, с массивами это не так. Если уж разговор зашёл об образовательных целях, то это просто необходимо упомянуть.

Comment: @ixSci: Это почему это? Эквивалентность `*( *(a + x) + y)` и `a[x][y]` одинаково справедлива и для указателей, и для массивов, и для произвольной смеси тех и других. Семантика такого выражения отличается для указателей и для массивов, но синтаксическая эквивалентность - стопроцентная. Более того, `a[x][y]` *всегда* интерпретируется компилятором именно как `*( *(a + x) + y)` (в терминах встроенных операторов, разумеется).

Comment: @AnT, спасибо, не знал. На мой взгляд это было идиотское решения, со стороно разработчиков стандарта. Запись вида `*( *(a + x) + y)`  совершенно не имеет смысла для двумерного массива, который не является двойным указателем.

Comment: @ixSci: Не понимаю, что имеется в виду под "не имеет смысла". Это не более чем вложенная сама в себя запись `*(a + i)` для одномерного массива. А так как *встроенный* двумерный массив - это просто массив массивов, то вложенность оправдана и ожидаема. Семантическая разница между массивами и указателями, которую я упомянул выше, заключается лишь в том, что в случае массива `a` указатель для `+` образуется в результатате *array-to-pointer conversion*, а в случае указателя `a` указатель просто читается из памяти (*lvalue-to-rvalue conversion*).

Comment: @AnT, не имеет смысла, потому что двумерный массив это одинарный указатель. А в записи выше происходит два разыменования указателя, что может сбить человека с толку, что [][] это **. Но [][] в ** не конвертируется, хотя по той же логике должен был бы.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну если строго, то массив - это вообще не указатель. Массив это массив, который умеет неявно *преобразовываться* к указателю. Массив `T [m][n]` сразу неявно преобразуется к указателю `T (*)[n]`, который участвует во внутреннем выражении вида `*(a + i)`. Но результат последнего - это тоже массив типа `T [n]`, который в свою очередь тоже сразу преобразуется к указателю `T *`, который участвует во внешнем выражении вида `*(a + i)`. Вот так и "появляются" два указателя. На самом деле изначально никаких указателей нет вообще. Они рождаются "на лету" один за другим по мере необходимости.

Comment: @AnT, да это всё понятно. Причина как раз  в том, что этот синтаксис(точнее его исполнение) коренным образом отличается для указателей и массивов. Он реально был придуман для указателей(для которых он полностью логичен), а массивы, уже просто приплели. Видимо для того, чтобы была похожая адресация. Не знаю, на мой взгляд это только запутывает. Ну да ладно, есть так есть. Будем с этим жить. Ещё раз спасибо за разъяснение, я до сегодняшнего дня думал, что этот синаксис принадлежит указателям безраздельно.

Comment: @ixSci: Я бы так не сказал. В пердшественниках С - языках B и BCPL - массивы *физически* реализовывались, как указатели. Но в этих языках не было `struct`. Деннис Ричи ввел в С тип `struct` и тут же заметил, что реализация массивов, как физических указателей, больше не работает. Например, такой тип как `struct S { int a[10]; };` становится трудно копировать - нельзя просто сделать `memcpy`. И массивы в С были переработаны: они перестали быть указателями, но продолжали "эмулировать" указатели внешне, через неявное array-to-pointer conversion. Это было задумано именно так изначально.

Comment: То есть массивы не "просто приплели", а работа "через указатель" для них является родной еще со времен языка B. Просто в языке С этот указатель стал неявным, но поведение B эмулировалось умышленно. Об этом можно почитать у самого Денниса Ричи (на Bell Labs его странички вроде снесли): http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~lib113/reference/c/c_history.html, см. раздел "Embryonic C"

Comment: @AnT, спасибо, почитаю!

Comment: Ага, его странички не снесли, а сделали под `.co` вместо `.com` (???): http://cm.bell-labs.co/who/dmr/chist.html

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотели использовать некий "объект-пару индексов" для индексации вашей матрицы, как это предлагалось делать в принятом вами же ответе на предыдущий ваш вопрос, то для этого надо было сначала завести специальный тип парного матричного индекса

```
class Matrix{

  struct Index {
    int i, j;
  };

  ...
```

А затем уже использовать этот тип в качестве параметра в вашем операторе индексации

```
int &operator[](const Index &index)
{ 
    return p[index.i][index.j]; 
};

const int &operator[](const Index &index) const {
    return p[index.i][index.j];
};
```

Но вызывать такой оператор индексации придется несколько по-другому

```
cout << a[{ 2, 1 }];
```

а не так, как у вас написано.

Если вам такой вариант не нравится, то, как я говорил в комментариях к вашему предыдущему вопросу, сначала разберитесь, что же вы понимаете под операцией индексации, а уж потом занимайтесь ее реализацией. Вот и сечас, я вижу, вы не задумываясь бросились в принципиально иную реализацию, не понимая толком, что она делает...

Answer (score 1):

Создаете класс Index

```
class Index {
    int n_, m_;
public:
    Index(int n, int m):  n_(n), m_(m) {
    }
    int n() {
        return n_;
    }
    int m() {
        return m_;
    }
}
```

В классе Matrix:

```
int &operator[](const Index &index){ 
    return p[index.n()][index.m()]; 
};
```

Использование:

```
std::cout << a[Index(2,1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Оператор индексации может быть написан следующим образом. Я упущу детали определения самого класса, так как уже неоднократно в других ваших вопросах ответчиками было указано на недостатки вашего определения класса. Но по крайней мере вы можете посмотреть, как правильно определить деструктор класса.:)

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class Matrix
{
private:    
    int n = 0, m = 0;
    int **p = nullptr;
public:
    Matrix( int n, int m ) : n( n ), m( m )
    {
        p = new int *[n];
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) p[i] = new int[m];
    }
    ~Matrix()
    {
        if ( p )
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) delete []p[i];
            delete []p;
        }
    }

    const int * operator []( int i ) const
    {
        return p[i];
    }

    int * operator []( int i )
    {
        return p[i];
    }


    int rows() const { return n; }
    int columns() const { return m; }
};


int main()
{
    Matrix m( 3, 4 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < m.rows(); i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m.columns(); j++ ) m[i][j] = i * m.columns() + j;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < m.rows(); i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m.columns(); j++ ) std::cout << std::setw( 2 ) << m[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Ее вывод на консоль будет следующим:

```
 0  1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11
```